# How do I Install Retrospect backup client on 14.04?

Tags: backup

Retrospect Backup client require 32-bit libraries. On the 12.04 LTS I would install ia32-libs. That is no longer an available package and it appears that I must determine more precisely what libraries are needed for this closed-source app. The vendor doesn't support Ubuntu, just RedHat.

Comment: This is an odd system - I'm new, with zero reputation, so I can't give it the up vote it deserves, nor add a comment that the amd64 setting did not work on my i386 PC. We'll see what this does when I try to save it...

Comment: (agreed) You should be able to do the install without changing the i386 to amd64 and be good to go. You could also leave out the :i386 on the dependency. The package is already i386 ready which requires those steps to get the 64-bit system working. In other words, it's easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create the package** follow the steps below.

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien -g --scripts linux_client-7_7_100.rpm
cd retroclient-7.7.100
sudo vim debian/control
# change the Architecture from i386 to amd64 on line 7
# add libstdc++6:i386 to the Depends line separated by a comma on line 8
# see below if this is confusing
sudo debian/rules binary
```

That drops retroclient_7.7.100-2_amd64.deb in the same directory as you originally ran alien from. If I were you I'd rename that retroclient_Ubuntu144.deb since it is Ubuntu 14.04+ specific. It might work on 13.10. I forget when they changed the 32-bit stuff.

**To install from your newly created .deb package** run this procedure.

If you can remember the package name exactly and remember to install libstc++:i386 ahead of time, you can skip the second step and install the dependency first. I'm sure I usually won't remember so this expects my failure and integrates it.

```
#This will fail with the dependency issues if you haven't resolved them yet.
sudo dpkg -i retroclient_7.7.100-2_amd64.deb

#This will install the dependencies and automatically take you back to configuring RetroClient.
sudo apt-get -f install

#This will check the status to confirm it setup the startup scripts and started rcl.
sudo service rcl status
```

*Look at you, you beautiful, smart person you. You defeated the system and installed the retrospect client on a system that the vendor doesn't support. Take pride in your accomplishments!*

---

Here is the **content of my debian/control** file exactly in case the instructions above were unclear.

```
Source: retroclient
Section: alien
Priority: extra
Maintainer: me <me@ubuntu>

Package: retroclient
Architecture: amd64
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, libstdc++6:i386
Description: A Retrospect client application
 This is the client application to be used in
 conjuction with the Retrospect application for Windows.
 This application will enable backing up, restoring,
 duplicating, and scanning files or entire volumes.
 .
 (Converted from a rpm package by alien version 8.90.)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Now with the new version 9.5**

They have a 64-bit installer. This installer is a bit buggy. I'm keeping my changes to the installer updated on the Retrospect forums:

http://forums.retrospect.com/index.php?/topic/151358-new-installer-bug-fixes-and-reports/

14.04 is no officially supported, but 12.04 is not. I have however had some mixed success with the installer on 12.04. I have one server that isn't, but another is. Also, the 9.5 client appears to work fine with the 7.7 version of the server.

NOTE: The 64-bit installer still needs to have the libc6-i386 package installed.